# Javascript's alert box doesn't appear in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, parallels, alert

System: Windows Server 2012 via Parallel's 11

I'm experiencing a strange problem on Google Chrome 53.0.2 with the Javascript alert box.

As you may know, when the alert() function is fired in the browser, a box will immediately be displayed in the browser window. Strangely, in my Chrome browser, the alert box does not appear until after I click mouse.

For example: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81t3a53f/) should show an alert dialog immediately after you click the button. And, in fact, it works fine in my Firefox and IE browsers. However, the alert dialog does not popup in my Chrome browser until after I click my mouse. In other words, I click the button and nothing happens. If I click my mouse again, the alert dialog is displayed.

In an attempt to fix the problem, I uninstalled Chrome (as well as all the Google folders that are created in the Registry, Programs x86, AppData, etc.) - Also, I have disabled all my Chrome extensions and have tried using Incognito. None of the above has fixed the problem.

Also, worth mentioning, this alert() problem does NOT occur on Chrome on my Mac.

What is causing this problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue.
After much testing I was able to correct this by the following means

1. Settings> Show advanced settings
2. Scroll to bottom
3. Remove the checkmark from "use hardware acceleration when available"